# Scroll views in framelayout over z-axis

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I am trying to create a view I found on "developer.android.com", namely the top left one on the following image (I am not allowed to post images):

[Layout from developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/design/media/app_structure_overview.png)

It looks like one can choose between different 'cards' which are layered on top of each other.

I found that a `FrameLayout` will layer multiple child views, so I created the view in following way:

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

This will give the image of multiple views layered, but I don't know how to cycle through the different views. I tried looking for scrolling over the z-axis in a `FrameLayout`, but this did not give me any helpful results.

So my question is: How can I create a layout which allows scrolling through the child views over the z-axis by swiping the screen? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd just use `StackView`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/StackView.html

Comment: Seems promising, I am going to try that. Could you make an answer so I can accept it if it works? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It looks like one can choose between different 'cards' which are layered on top of each other.

Android has a `StackView` widget that offers this UI. You tend to see it more in app widgets, as typical Android app widgets like Photo Gallery and YouTube employ a `StackView`.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/WidgetCatalog/StackView) demonstrating the use of a `StackView` in a traditional UI, not in an app widget.

Comment: This will work, thanks. I cannot clone your code though, I get a 403 Forbidden error. Accepted your answer.

Comment: @tmkhva: The link is to an individual Android project in a rather large GitHub repository, containing hundreds of Android projects from [a book that I wrote](http://commonsware.com/Android). You cannot just clone those directories, at least not easily. You can clone the whole repo, or download the whole repo as a ZIP file, though. Or, just browse the project through the GitHub Web interface and use it as a point of reference. I apologize for any confusion.